# get the IP from file1 and update it in file2

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have two files: one file has a list of IPs that needs to get replaced in another file. My files are as below:

**file1.txt**

```
173.43.24.67
170.34.24.59
172.83.47.83
160.28.39.49
```

**file2.txt**

```
### HostList ##
[group]
dev  ansible_host=pub_ip1 ansible_user=ubuntu  
test ansible_host=pub_ip2 ansible_user=ubuntu  
prod ansible_host=pub_ip3 ansible_user=ubuntu
uat  ansible_host=pub_ip4 ansible_user=ubuntu
```

**Expected output**

```
### HostList ##
[group]
dev  ansible_host=173.43.24.67 ansible_user=ubuntu  
test ansible_host=170.34.24.59 ansible_user=ubuntu  
prod ansible_host= 172.83.47.83 ansible_user=ubuntu
uat  ansible_host=160.28.39.49 ansible_user=ubuntu
```

It would be great if someone could help me to achieve the above.

Comment: Should `ansible_host=pub_ip3` be `ansible_host=pub_ip4` in the last file of `file2.txt`?

Comment: @fpmurphy yes its typeo error.updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in $(cat file1); do sed -i "0,/pub_ip/s/pub_ip./$i/g" file2; done
```

output

```
### HostList ##
[group]
dev  ansible_host=173.43.24.67 ansible_user=ubuntu  
test ansible_host=170.34.24.59 ansible_user=ubuntu  
prod ansible_host=172.83.47.83 ansible_user=ubuntu
uat  ansible_host=160.28.39.49 ansible_user=ubuntu
```

Comment: Kumar.. thanks a lot its working perfectly fine

Comment: `for i in $(cat file1)` is an anti-pattern, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001, and the `0,/pub_ip` in your sed script is doing nothing, and the `pub_ip.` regexp means it'd fail if `pub_ip10=` or higher appeared in the input, and the `g` at the end of the sed command means you're trying to do the replacement multiple times per line when you actually only want it once.

Answer (score 1):

You got to remove the first two lines of file2.txt first and then:

```
$ paste file1.txt file2.txt  | tr '=' ' ' | awk '{printf("%s %s=%s %s\n",$2,$3,$1,$5)}' | column -t
dev   ansible_host=173.43.24.67  ansible_user
test  ansible_host=170.34.24.59  ansible_user
prod  ansible_host=172.83.47.83  ansible_user
uat   ansible_host=160.28.39.49  ansible_user
```

Comment: You don't need the `tr`, just set FS in awk to include `=`. e.g. `awk -F'[ =]' ...`

Answer (score 1):

This should work everywhere:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {m[NR]=$0}

    NR != FNR && f {
        sub(/=.*/, "=" m[NR-FNR], $2)
        print
    }

    NR != FNR && !f {
        print
        if (/^[[]/) f = 1
    }
' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ips[NR]=$1; next} FNR>2{sub(/=[^ ]+/,"="ips[FNR-2])} 1' file1.txt file2.txt
### HostList ##
[group]
dev  ansible_host=173.43.24.67 ansible_user=ubuntu
test ansible_host=170.34.24.59 ansible_user=ubuntu
prod ansible_host=172.83.47.83 ansible_user=ubuntu
uat  ansible_host=160.28.39.49 ansible_user=ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0):

Another sed based on the 1st answer.

`paste <(sed -n '3,$p' file2.txt ) file1.txt |sed "s/\(^.*=\)\(pub_ip.\)\(.*\)\t\(.*\)/\1\4\3/"| cat <(head -2 file2.txt) -`

Output:

```
### HostList ##
[group]
dev  ansible_host=173.43.24.67 ansible_user=ubuntu  
test ansible_host=170.34.24.59 ansible_user=ubuntu  
prod ansible_host=172.83.47.83 ansible_user=ubuntu
uat  ansible_host=160.28.39.49 ansible_user=ubuntu
```

Edit:

`paste <(sed -n '3,$p' file2.txt ) file1.txt |sed "s/\(^.*=\)\(pub_ip[[:digit:]]*\)\(.*\)\t\(.*\)/\1\4\3/"| cat <(head -2 file2.txt) -`

After the pub_ip part we want to choose any digit.

Explanation.
 `<(sed -n '3,$p' file2.txt )` We cut the 1st two line from the file2. The paste command merge this and the file1.

Output of `paste <(sed -n '3,$p' file2.txt ) file1.txt` :

```
dev  ansible_host=pub_ip1 ansible_user=ubuntu   173.43.24.67
test ansible_host=pub_ip2 ansible_user=ubuntu   170.34.24.59
prod ansible_host=pub_ip3 ansible_user=ubuntu   172.83.47.83
uat  ansible_host=pub_ip14 ansible_user=ubuntu  160.28.39.49
```

After that, we split the lines in this file for four parts.

```
(dev  ansible_host=) 1st
(pub_ip[digits]) 2nd
( ansible_user=ubuntu) 3rd (plus tab)
173.43.24.67 4th.
```

and print the 1st,4th, and 3rd parts.
Output:

```
dev  ansible_host=173.43.24.67 ansible_user=ubuntu  
test ansible_host=170.34.24.59 ansible_user=ubuntu  
prod ansible_host=172.83.47.83 ansible_user=ubuntu
uat  ansible_host=160.28.39.49 ansible_user=ubuntu
```

=> we just need to join this output and the 1st two lines from file2